# How do I handle slow API responses in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, rest, timeout

In order to prevent long-running API calls that are unable to fetch data or are experiencing database issues, I want to implement a timeout mechanism in my REST API. I have tried to implement and use this in my code, but it does not seem to be working. The wait time is set to 5 seconds. If there is no response within that time, the API should return a **"timeout- server taking too long to respond"** error.

Below are the server and one of the test routes

**Server.js**

```
const express=require('express')
const app=require('./app')
const http=require('http');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
const dotenv=require('dotenv');
const ConnectToDb=require('./config/db-connection');
const register=require('./api/routes/auth');
const errorHandler = require('./api/middlewares/errorHandler');
 
//setting .env file variables
dotenv.config({path:'./.env'})
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 5001;
// ConnectToDb();
  
const server=http.createServer(app);
 
 
ConnectToDb().then(()=>{
    server.listen(PORT,()=>{
        console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
    })
});
 
var request=http.request({
    port:PORT,
    host:'192.168.1.247',
    timeout: 5000,
});
request.end();
request.on('timeout', (res)=>{
    console.log("timeout- server taking too long to respond");
  });
```

**test.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        res.status(400).json({message:'Testing'})
    },10000)

})

module.exports=router;
```

The router timeout is set to 10 seconds, while the server request timeout is set to 5 seconds. In this case, the response from the server should be **"timeout - server taking too long to respond"** because the functionality in the route is taking longer than the threshold set on the server's request object, which is 5 seconds.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Why  `server.listen` ?

Comment: To Start the server on the PORT specified in short

Comment: Ok, but why not app.listen()?

Comment: I'm using http server on it.As http offers more features

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling everything in request object simply bind everything for single route and start timer on request invoke and send 503 if request getting processed more than 5 seconds , you can add this  in middleware as well to make for all routes

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

```
app.get('/your-route', (req, res) => {
  const timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds in milliseconds

  // Set a timer to respond with a timeout message if the request takes too long
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    res.status(503).json({ error: 'Server took too long to respond' });
  }, timeout);

  // Simulate a delay longer than 5 seconds for testing purposes
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearTimeout(timer); // Clear the timer when the request is complete
    res.send('Request processed successfully');
  }, 6000); // Simulating 6-second processing time
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```